# PyTorch FasterRCNN gives no output

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, torchvision

I am trying to build a simple object detector using the torchvision pretrained model FasterRCNN. I want to be able to input an image, predict the objects, and output that image with the bounding boxes. I have loaded the torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2 and its weights, input an image, but it gives me no predictions at all.

Here is my detector class, detector.py:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from config import device
from torchvision.models.detection import FasterRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_Weights, FasterRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_V2_Weights
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor, fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2
from torchvision.transforms import transforms as T
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF

CLASSES = ['__background__', 'person', 'bicycle', 'car', 'motorcycle', 'airplane', 'bus', 'train', 'truck', 'boat', 'traffic light', 'fire hydrant', 'N/A', 'stop sign', 'parking meter', 'bench', 'bird', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'sheep', 'cow', 'elephant', 'bear', 'zebra', 'giraffe', 'N/A', 'backpack', 'umbrella', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'handbag', 'tie', 'suitcase', 'frisbee', 'skis', 'snowboard', 'sports ball', 'kite', 'baseball bat', 'baseball glove', 'skateboard', 'surfboard', 'tennis racket', 'bottle', 'N/A', 'wine glass', 'cup', 'fork', 'knife', 'spoon', 'bowl', 'banana', 'apple', 'sandwich', 'orange', 'broccoli', 'carrot', 'hot dog', 'pizza', 'donut', 'cake', 'chair', 'couch', 'potted plant', 'bed', 'N/A', 'dining table', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'toilet', 'N/A', 'tv', 'laptop', 'mouse', 'remote', 'keyboard', 'cell phone', 'microwave', 'oven', 'toaster', 'sink', 'refrigerator', 'N/A', 'book', 'clock', 'vase', 'scissors', 'teddy bear', 'hair drier', 'toothbrush']

class detector():
  def __init__(self, model_path,threshold=0.3):
    self.threshold = threshold
    self.model = self.load_model(model_path)
  def load_model(self, model_path=None):
    """   
    Loads a pretrained model and state_dict if desired 

    Todo: implement channels for IR image data
    implement channels polarimetric data"""

    print("Loading model...")
    model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2(weights=FasterRCNN_ResNet50_FPN_V2_Weights.DEFAULT)
    print("Loading model...done")

    # get the number of input features 
    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    # # define a new head for the detector with required number of classes
    num_classes = len(CLASSES)
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes) 

    if model_path is not None:
      print("Loading model from:", model_path)
      model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path), map_location=device)

    return model

  def train(self, dataloader, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs):
    # loads a custom dataset and trains the model with it

    "Not implemented"
    return None

  def detect(self, image):
    """
    image: tensor
    """

    transform=T.Compose([
              T.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225))
        ])

    norm_tensor = transform(image.type(torch.FloatTensor)) #normalize the image
    image_tensor = (norm_tensor - torch.min(norm_tensor))/(torch.max(norm_tensor) - torch.min(norm_tensor))*(1 - 0) + 0 # min max scaling from 0 to 1

    if len(image_tensor.shape) == 3:   #if input is single image, wrap in a batch
      image_tensor = image_tensor.unsqueeze(0)
    #else if input is a batch, do nothing

    image_tensor = image_tensor.to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
      self.model.to(device)
      self.model.eval()
      outputs = self.model(image_tensor)

    outputs = [{k: v.to('cpu') for k, v in t.items()} for t in outputs] #move outputs to cpu

    boxes = outputs[0]['boxes']
    scores = outputs[0]['scores']
    labels = outputs[0]['labels']

    # filter out boxes according to threshold
    conf_mask = scores > self.threshold
    boxes = boxes[conf_mask]
    labels = labels[conf_mask]

    # get all the predicited class names
    pred_classes = [CLASSES[i] for i in labels.cpu()]

    return boxes, pred_classes
```

Here is my visualizer, visualizer.py:

```
def image_visualizer(detector,img_path, tensorboard=False):
    print('Loading image...')

    img_tensor = read_image(img_path) # C H W
    boxes, pred_cls = detector.detect(img_tensor)
    if boxes.shape[0] == 0:
        print("No objects detected")
        return

    bbox_img = draw_bounding_boxes(img_tensor, boxes, labels=pred_cls)

    if tensorboard:
        print("Saving output to tensorboard...")
        writer = SummaryWriter()
        writer.add_image('image', bbox_img)
        writer.close()
        print("Image saved")
    else:
        write_png(bbox_img, 'detection_img.png')
```

And the usage is:

```
from detector import detector
from visualizer import image_visualizer

image_path = "sailboat.jpg"
predictor = detector(threshold = .3, model_path = None)
image_visualizer(predictor, image_path,  tensorboard=opts.tensorboard)
```

I played around with the normalization and scaling. The torch documentation for fasterrcnn states the input values should be between [0,1]. If I don't scale to [0,1] but to [-1,1] I get predictions but it's 100 completely bogus, low confidence predictions. Normalization seems to have no effect. Loading the model without modifying the in_features or box_predictor also has the same effect where I get predictions, but it's 100 bogus predictions. I'm not sure what to do. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my problem, this section should be removed:

```
    # get the number of input features 
    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    # # define a new head for the detector with required number of classes
    num_classes = len(CLASSES)
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
```

I don't understand why it should or shouldn't be in there, I followed a few tutorials suggestions to do so, but removing it seemed to fix the problem.